# Generate Access-Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

I want get the access_token after expire access_topken using refresh token in MVC controller how hit refresh_token api to access access_token and refresh_token in mvc controller ?

```
[Route("RefreshToken")]
 [HttpGet]
 public Token RefreshToken(string refreshtoken)
 {
        var Refresh_Token = context.UserRefreshTokens.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Token == refreshtoken);
        if (Refresh_Token == null)
        {

            var res = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.userEmail == userEmail);
            if (res != null)
            {
                UserForLogin newObj = new UserForLogin();

                newObj.userEmail = userEmail;
                newObj.password = res.password;

                var token = GenerateToken(newObj);
                var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();
                if (token != null)
                {
                    return new Token
                    {
                        Access_Token = token.ToString(),
                        Refresh_Token = refreshToken.Token
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        else if ( Refresh_Token.Expire < DateTime.Now)
        {
            var res = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.userEmail == userEmail);
            if (res != null)
            {
                UserForLogin newObj = new UserForLogin();

                newObj.userEmail = userEmail;
                newObj.password = res.password;

                var token = GenerateToken(newObj);
                var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();
                if (token != null)
                {
                    return new Token
                    {
                        Access_Token = token.ToString(),
                        Refresh_Token = refreshtoken
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        else
        {

            var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.userEmail == userEmail);
            if (user != null)
            {
                UserForLogin newObj = new UserForLogin();

                newObj.userEmail = userEmail;
                newObj.password = user.password;

                string token = GenerateToken(newObj);
                if (token != null)
                {
                    return new Token
                    {
                        Access_Token = token,
                        Refresh_Token = refreshtoken
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we want to integrate Jwt authentication into the MVC project, we might have  code like below in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

Then we will need a Bearer token in request header to visit the Controller API.

We could use code below to generate the access token.

```
private string generateJwt() {
      var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
      var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

      var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "user_name"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user_email"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim("role","admin"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
            };

      var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

      return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
  }
```

Refresh token is used to generate a new access token when it's expired or anytime you want to generate a new access token. We could follow the idea from [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-in-net-6-0/) to define and store the refresh token.

```
private static string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[64];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
```

Upon the user signing in, we call the method to generate the access token and the refresh token. We could store the refresh token into the database along with the expire time for this user. When this user wants to refresh the access token, the app should call the refresh method with the access token and the refresh token. Comparing the refresh token first with the one stored in database, if they are the same and hasn't expired, we could call the method for  generating access token and refresh token, and update the database with the new refresh token, then return new access token and refresh token back to the client.

```
//for refreshing, getting refresh token first and validate the token received in the request
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
if (user == null || user.RefreshToken != refreshToken || user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime <= DateTime.Now)
{
    return BadRequest("Invalid access token or refresh token");
}
  
//generate new token when user sign in or wants to refresh
var token = CreateToken(authClaims);
var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();

//store refresh token into database
user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(refreshTokenValidityInDays);
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

//return token to the clients
return Ok(new
{
    Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
    RefreshToken = refreshToken,
    Expiration = token.ValidTo
});
```